# Websense is blocking our website as “Potentially Damaging Content”

Tags: spam, spam-prevention, spam-blocker, filtering, penalty

A lot of people are complaining that my company's website `www.justjus.com` is being blocked by their organisations.  Anyone that has tried to access our website from a large organisation has been unable to do so.

Is there any reason why this is and is there any way in which I can fix the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a website being misclassified by Websense?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3804/how-do-i-prevent-a-website-being-misclassified-by-websense)

Answer (score 0):

Websense has [this advice on their website](http://www.websense.com/content/blocked-by-websense.aspx):

> **What you can do if you feel a website has been incorrectly categorized.**
>
> Ask your Help Desk or IT administrator to change a website's category (they can override the Websense category). You can also suggest that Websense researchers reevaluate a categorization by e-mailing suggest@websense.com.

So it sounds like you can have the people that are complaining talk to the their IT departments and have it fixed for *them*.    You should also email Websense to let them know about the error.